# Show that $\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \bigg] = 1$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ with each number $n \in S$ with probability $1/2$ independently; in other words we run through all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and each time $n$ becomes part of $S$ with chance $1/2$ independently.Prove that
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n}  = \frac{1}{2} \bigg] = 1$$
>
> Hint: For fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n$ use the Chernoff's bound to find an upper bound for
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \bigg\lvert \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n}  -\frac{1}{2} \bigg\rvert \ge \varepsilon\bigg]$$
>
> and apply union bound to show that
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \exists n \ge n_0 \text{ with } \bigg\lvert \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n}  -\frac{1}{2} \bigg\rvert \ge \varepsilon\bigg] \overset{N \rightarrow \infty}{=} \mathcal{o}(1) $$
>
> Does this also work if we use  Chebyshev's bound?
>
> Remark: $[n]$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

First we note that $\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(X_k)$ for $X_k \sim Ber(1/2)$ i.i.d. Thus for $Y_n := \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n}$ we have $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{V}[Y_n] = 1/4$.

$$\mathbb{P}\bigg[\bigg\lvert X - \mathbb{E}[X] \bigg\rvert \ge \varepsilon\bigg]=\mathbb{P}\bigg[\bigg\lvert \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n} - \frac{1}{2} \bigg\rvert \ge \varepsilon\bigg] \le \exp\bigg(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2(1/2 + \varepsilon/3)}  \bigg)$$

However,  when I try to apply the union bound I get

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigg[ \exists n \ge N \text{ with } \bigg\lvert \frac{\lvert S \cap [n] \rvert}{n}  -\frac{1}{2} \bigg\rvert  \ge \varepsilon\bigg] &\le \sum_{k \ge N}^\infty \mathbb{P}\bigg[\bigg\lvert Y_k -\frac{1}{2}\bigg\rvert \ge \varepsilon \bigg] \\
&= \sum_{k \ge N}^\infty \exp\bigg(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2(1/2 + \varepsilon/3)} \bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: 'Let $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ with each number $n\in S$ with probability $1/2$': would you provide more details on this?

Comment: @Snoop: I made an edit; I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: We could rewrite $|S \cap [n]|$ in the following way:
$|S \cap [n]|=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(X_k)$ where $X_k\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ IID. Would you agree with this?

Comment: This OP has asked several recent questions, most of which neglect to state anything about a crucial assumption of independence.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, you are right. I made an edit.

Comment: @Snoop: You are right, I made an edit.

Comment: @3nondatur I would then suggest that the result is given by the law of large numbers, which makes this exercise's setting peculiar. Where is this from?

Comment: This is an exercise from my combinatorics lecture. I do know the law of large numbers, but I have to use the union bound here.